# Getting the Products which have a specific product among the Up-Sells

Tags: magento-1.9, product, collection, product-collection, up-sells

How can I get the list of products which have a specific product among their Up-Sells?

To be more specific, I'm getting a list of products with a specific attribute; I need to remove those products from the Up-Sells list across all the products in the Database, so, I'd like to filter the collection in some way.

Magento CE 1.9

Answer (score 1):

Product relations are stored in the `catalog_product_link` table, where upsells are distinguished with `link_type_id=4`. You can look up the link types in `catalog_product_link_type`:

```
mysql> select * from  catalog_product_link_type;
+--------------+------------+
| link_type_id | code       |
+--------------+------------+
|            1 | relation   |
|            3 | super      |
|            4 | up_sell    |
|            5 | cross_sell |
+--------------+------------+
```

The linked product, i.e. the product in the upsell list is determined by `linked_product_id`.

To list the products, join the tablt to product collection using this column.

> To be more specific, I'm getting a list of products with a specific
>   attribute; I need to remove those products from the Up-Sells list
>   across all the products in the Database

But it's good that you were more specific because this is much simpler. I assume it is a one time thing, so you can do it right away in MySQL:

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_link WHERE linked_product_id IN ( [LIST] );
```

`[LIST]` can either be a comma separated list of product ids or a subquery in the form `SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity [JOIN] [WHERE]`.